# Punctuation marks in use of "up to and including"

Tags: punctuation

What punctuation marks (or paraphrasing) should be used to make this sentence easier to read:

> Releases up to and including Product v3.1 do not have this feature.

Is it ok to say the following?

> Releases up to, and including, Product v3.1 do not have this feature.

Are there better alternatives?

Comment: Either of your examples is fine. I would go without the commas here.

Comment: Thanks Dave! Could you please put this comment as an answer so that I can accept it. By the way, after reading your profile, I am a bit unsure about your suggestion :), especially this part: "...but that won't stop me from providing you with my unfounded assertions as though they are facts"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either example sounds natural. However, I recommend the one with no commas. The commas are not necessary.

Comment: I rather strongly prefer the version without commas.